# vim how to come back to file browser (no plugins)

Tags: vim

I'm working (with vim) on this tree of files::

```
$ tree /tmp/folder/
/tmp/folder/
├── dir1
│   └── file74.txt
└── dir2
    ├── file13.txt
    └── file22.txt
$
```

If I start `vim` with a folder as argument::

```
$ vim /tmp/folder
```

I can navigate throught files, it's pretty cool.

Then selecting a file I can edit it.

My question is how from a file I'm editing can I come back to the file browser ?

PS: vanilla vim, no pluging please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is obviously in the documentation: `:help netrw`.

```
:Rex
```